# How to use doctrine QueryBuilder in a nested loop

Tags: doctrine-orm, query-builder

I’m using QueryBuilder in the in the following way:

```
    $qb = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder();

    $qb->select('m')
        ->from('MyEntity', 'm');

    $query = $qb->getQuery();
    $collection = $query->getResult();

    foreach ($collection as $item) {
        $qb = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
        $qb->update('MyEntity ', 'm')
                ->set('m.myItem', '?1');

        $query = $qb->getQuery();
        $result = $query->execute();

    }
```

(I've remove a lot of details in order to focus on the gist of the question)

How should this script be written?

- Is it appropriate to reuse `$qb` or should I use `$qb1`, `$qb2`,
  etc.?
- In this particular script, the results of the first instance of
  QueryBuilder get passed into an array `$collection` before the next
  steps, so I assume    that I’m done with the first instance of
  QueryBuilder at that time.     Does there need to be something like
  `$qb->close` before moving on?
- Is it necessary to say `$qb = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder();`
  more than once?

Comment: looping over all items and execute query after query is bad for performance, more informations about what you try to achieve i will try to give you better answer.

Comment: what I'm trying to do is detailed here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29355394/how-to-renumber-a-column-in-doctrine